# Calcular ID vindo do Banco de dados

Tags: php

Estou fazendo a manutenção em um sistema PHP com Mysql. Observei que no tabela de usuário tem um campo chamado código. Esse campo armazena da seguinte forma:

```
id_usuario | codigo_usuario
   1            00001
```

E o último valor:

```
   id_usuario | codigo_usuario
       7810         07810
```

Como eu poderia calcular, pode ser em PHP ou dentro da própria tabela para que o próximos registros mantenham esse padrão? Ex:

```
  id_usuario | codigo_usuario
     7811          07811
```

Comment: Basicamente fazendo um `LPAD` no id com comprimento 5, mas e quando chegar em 99999, o que acontecerá depois?

Comment: Pois é.... o tipo desse campo é int(5).

Comment: alterei para int(11).

Comment: Se ele é `int`, não irá existir esses zeros à esquerda e, assim, será o mesmo valor que o id.

Comment: Certo. Ele está dessa forma: `codigo_usuario int(5) UN zerofill` . Parece que o colega atribuiu esse valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer no seu php da seguinte forma:

1) faça o insert no seu banco

2) Logo em seguida pegue o ultimo id inserido com a função abaixo

```
`$ultimoId= mysqli_insert_id($con)`;
```

3) depois coloque os zeros a esquerda com o seguinte cod:

```
$cod_usuario=sprintf("%05d", $ultimoId);
```

4) Faça um update na sua tabela onde você sete o `$cod_usuario` onde o id for `$ultimoId`

Comment: Obrigado Jasar.